does setOnCloseRequest exist in preferencesfx?
Im trying to make a settings window with preferencesfx, and im trying to cap the amount of settings windows that can exist to 1 using a boolean. The boolean is automatically defined to false when the program starts and is defined as true when a settings window opens. However Im trying to make it go back to false with setOnCloseRequest and i cant seem to find the method or anything similar
The Boolean obviously doesnt get back to false at any time and when i close the settings window it will not open again (as the boolean has been set to true).
Is there any method similar to setOnCloseRequest within preferencesfx or a better way to cap the amount of settings windows?

I haven't used preferencesfx (I assume you are referring to this), but a quick look suggests it fires off its own PreferencesFxEvent when the dialog is closed, so you can just add an event handler for that.
